# How to tell git to use certain ssh IdentityFile when cloning from certain host?

Tags: git, ssh

In the `~/.ssh/config` I have the following settings:

```
Host server1 
Hostname myhostname1
User nsurname
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/git1/id_rsa"

Host server2 
Hostname myhostname2
User nsurname
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/git2/id_rsa"
```

Then I run `git clone` command to download a repository from `myhostname1`. It works only if I have `id_rsa` placed directly in ´~/.ssh/´. So, it looks like I should pass some additional parameter to `git clone` in order it can find `id_rsa` inside `~/.ssh/git1`, not `~/.ssh`.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use gives you several options, to wear on different occasions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
Host myhostname1
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/git1/id_rsa"
```

in your config so the `ssh` is able to pair that hostname with that key. With the config you provided, it would be used only for `server1`.

If you want to use that key for all the hosts, there is possibility to set

```
Host *
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/git1/id_rsa"
```

Comment: Why the config I provided is unable to pair `myhostname2` with the key? For `server2` I use the same settings: `Host server2 
Hostname myhostname2
User nsurname
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/git2/id_rsa"`. Moreover, if I delete `server2` and leave only `server1` with the key putted inside sub-folder of ssh, then it doesn't work. It sees only keys putted directly into `ssh`...

Comment: Check manual page for `ssh_config`. It explains it quite well. The `Host` keyword matches against your commandline. Not the `Hostname` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple private keys (identity files) in ~/. ssh folder under different names say id_rsa_github, id_rsa_github, etc and reference them in ~/. ssh/config as you have done already.